# appropriate ICC

Tags: r, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

My apologies this is a rookie question, I am aware of what ICC(Intraclass correlation) is, and that it measures how strongly subjects in the same group resemble each other. However I am not sure how to estimate the ICC for a set of observation like this.

Id here represents subject Id, each subject is measured for three different parameters and Average is the average of those three parameters.

```
Id  Time    y1      y2      y3      Average
1   t1     16.11    14.40   2.49    11.00
1   t2     15.67    14.48   7.00    12.38
2   t3     11.24    17.32   3.68    10.75
3   t1     17.93    11.61   1.62    10.39
3   t2     11.82    14.96   8.08    11.62
4   t3     12.95    14.00   1.59    9.51
5   t1     12.68    10.02   1.59    8.10
5   t1     11.53    14.52   10.20   12.08
6   t2     11.74    11.85   3.26    8.95
```

Any suggestions or advise is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are your groups in this example? What is the measure you are interested in? ICC can vary based on the measure you are looking at: it could be different for y1, y2, y3. But we need to know the group.

Comment: @bzki, groups="ID", measure = "Average", is this helpful ? Thanks.